# Intent and getSerializableExtra value return

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, parameters, parameter-passing

In `onCreate` I get an extra serializable from intent into `itemsList` of my activity

```
itemsList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) intent
  .getSerializableExtra("sliding_menu_content");
```

then in the activity I add some other map elements to the `itemsList` array.
My surprise is that, changing the orientation of the device, `getSerializableExtra` returns the updated state of `itemsList` including all map elements additions. How is it possible?

**EDIT:**
My calling activity puts extras like this

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> startingList = 
   new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
i.putExtra("sliding_menu_content", startingList);
startActivity(i);
```

as I understand passing parameters, it is a hypothesis to evaluate, when I assign `itemsList` by `getSerializableExtra` I get not a **copy of its values** but I get a **copy of the pointer** to the original object passed by the calling activity (that is `startingList`), then every updates on it are updates on the original values.

Comment: Please check that you not invoke code that update the Intent in eg. #onResume

Comment: On which method did you add other map elements to the itemList array?

Comment: Checked: no changes on the Intent.

Comment: I add other items  in `onPostExecute` overriding onPostExecute()  of  a AsyncTask nested in a Fragment retained.

Comment: I edited my question with a hypothesis to evaluate, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know how Intent.putExtra() and Intent.getSerializable() works. Intent use Bundle to save paremeters, and If it is not a inter-process intent **the internal Bundle just save the original objects in a data map**. , the objects will **NOT be copyed**(do the unparcel and parcel stuff) , so what you get is still the original objects.

Comment: Interesting. Then the internal Bundle's scope of a Intent is it the process' scope?

Comment: Yes, when you need to exchange data between processes, like sending an intent to another application in other process. the intent will be write to another process through binder. The intent itself implements parcelable too.

Comment: I am trying the same passing a String object to intent's extras, getting it on `getStringExtra()` of the called activity, modifying its value, then rotate the device: there is not the same behavior, modified value is lost on rotation. Maybe it is true only for parceleable objects.